# Mesh arrow following the circuit. How? Bad minipage placement. How to fix?

Tags: equations, minipage, circuitikz

I don't know ii there a similar question (I didn't found anything). If so, please forgive me. Also sorry my incorrect english.

To the question. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{circuitikz}
      %
      % circuit
      %
      \draw
      (0,0) to [V = $U$] (0,3)
            to [short, i = $I$, -*] (3,3) -- (6,3)
            to [R = $R_2$, v = $U_2$, i = $I_2$] (6,0) -- (0,0)
      (3,3) to [R = $R_1$, v = $U_1$, i = $I_1$, -*] (3,0);
      %
      % mesh arrows
      %
      \draw
      %
      % mesh one (detailed explanation of the implementation)
      %
      [<-,% direction of the arrow
      > = triangle 45,% kind of the arrow end
      path picture =% allows ''to paint a picture'' inside of an other ''picture''
      {\node[anchor = center]% position of the inner ''picture''
      at (path picture bounding box.center)% bordering rectangle, centered inside the arrow (arrow is the outer ''picture'')
      {$M_1$};}]% text of the inner ''picture''
      (1.75,1)% coordinates of the arrow end
      arc% arc-shaped arrow
      (-60:% angle of the arrow start
      170:% angle of the arrow end
      .5);% radius of the arc
      %
      % mesh two (short implementation)
      %
      \draw
      [<-, > = triangle 45, path picture = {\node [anchor = center] at (path picture bounding box.center) {$M_2$};}] (4.75,1)
      arc (-60:170:.5);
      %
      % mesh three (short implementation)
      %
      \draw
      [<-, > = triangle 45, path picture = {\node [anchor = center, yshift = -15pt] at (path picture bounding box.center) {$M_3$};}] (.25,-.25)
      arc (-140:-10:3.75 and 2.5);
    \end{circuitikz}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    %
    % equations for mesh and knot
    %
    \begin{align*}
      &K  : \quad I   = I_1 + I_2\\
      &M_1: \quad -U  = -U_1\Leftrightarrow U = U_1 = R_1I_1\\
      &M_2: \quad U_1 = -U_2\\
      &M_3: \quad -U  = -U_2\Leftrightarrow U = U_2 = R_2I_2
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: My circuit with equations.]

**1.** The arrow of mesh three didn't follows the boundary of the circuit.

**2.** The position of equations isn't nice.

I want something like this (this picture is created with a graphic program):

[image: Circuit I want to have.]

**3.** I'm not happy how I implemented mesh arrows (with text inside). Is there another easier and optimal way?

Thank you for your answers and help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to create curved lines, including Beziers.  I also switched to top alignment between the `minipages` and moved the `tikzpicture` baseline to the top.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      %
      % circuit
      %
      \draw
      (0,0) to [V = $U$] (0,3)
            to [short, i = $I$, -*] (3,3) -- (6,3)
            to [R = $R_2$, v = $U_2$, i = $I_2$] (6,0) -- (0,0)
      (3,3) to [R = $R_1$, v = $U_1$, i = $I_1$, -*] (3,0);
      %
      % mesh arrows
      %
      \draw
      %
      % mesh one (detailed explanation of the implementation)
      %
      [<-,% direction of the arrow
      > = triangle 45,% kind of the arrow end
      path picture =% allows ''to paint a picture'' inside of an other ''picture''
      {\node[anchor = center]% position of the inner ''picture''
      at (path picture bounding box.center)% bordering rectangle, centered inside the arrow (arrow is the outer ''picture'')
      {$M_1$};}]% text of the inner ''picture''
      (1.75,1)% coordinates of the arrow end
      arc% arc-shaped arrow
      (-60:% angle of the arrow start
      170:% angle of the arrow end
      .5);% radius of the arc
      %
      % mesh two (short implementation)
      %
      \draw
      [<-, > = triangle 45, path picture = {\node [anchor = center] at (path picture bounding box.center) {$M_2$};}] (4.75,1)
      arc (-60:170:.5);
      %
      % mesh three (short implementation)
      %
      \node (mesh3) [below] at (0,0) {\phantom{$M_3$}};% reserve space below circuit for M_3
      \draw[->, > = triangle 45,thick] (current bounding box.east)% not the only way, just easy
        .. controls (current bounding box.south east) .. 
        (mesh3.south) node[above,pos=.9] {$M_3$};
    \end{circuitikz}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    %
    % equations for mesh and knot
    %
    \begin{align*}
      &K  : \quad I   = I_1 + I_2\\
      &M_1: \quad -U  = -U_1\Leftrightarrow U = U_1 = R_1I_1\\
      &M_2: \quad U_1 = -U_2\\
      &M_3: \quad -U  = -U_2\Leftrightarrow U = U_2 = R_2I_2
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Is there any special reason to use mini pages? To me it seems less complicated to draw one image  containing `circuitikz` specific drawings + node with equations (mesh lines are not so "big deal"):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[mesh/.style = {-{Triangle[flex]},thick}
                        ]
% circuit
\draw (0,0) to [V = $U$] (0,3)
            to [short, i = $I$, -*] (3,3) -- (6,3)
            to [R = $R_2$, v = $U_2$, i = $I_2$] (6,0) -- (0,0)
      (3,3) to [R = $R_1$, v = $U_1$, i = $I_1$, -*] (3,0);

% equations
\node  (m3) [text width=0.45\linewidth,below right] at (7,3.6)
{   \begin{align*}
      &K  : \quad I   = I_1 + I_2\\
      &M_1: \quad -U  = -U_1\Leftrightarrow U = U_1 = R_1I_1\\
      &M_2: \quad U_1 = -U_2\\
      &M_3: \quad -U  = -U_2\Leftrightarrow U = U_2 = R_2I_2
    \end{align*}
};
% mesh one 
\node (m1) at (1.5,1.5) {$M_1$};
\draw[mesh] 
    (m1) +  (210:5mm)    % start point 
    arc (210:-45:5mm);% start angle, end angle and arc's radius
% mesh two 
\node (m1) at (4.5,1.5) {$M_2$};
\draw[mesh]
    (m1) +  (210:5mm)    % start point
    arc (210:-45:5mm);% start angle, end angle and arc's radius
% mesh three (short implementation)
\draw[mesh,rounded corners=5mm] (m3.west) |- (0,-0.7) node[pos=0.9,above] {$M_3$}; 
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]