# Placing parts of circuit (capacitor...) relative to each other. Using names of circuits parts to place mesh arrows "intuitively" with "controls"

Tags: equations, minipage, circuitikz

This question is continuous my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309390/mesh-arrow-following-the-circuit-how-bad-minipage-placement-how-to-fix). Because of my reputation I can't add comments to answers. So I use the chance to thank [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) for his answer to my initial question. Also sorry for my incorrect english.

To the question:

For circuits I use the `circuitikz` syntax, example

```
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
  (0,0) to [V = $U$] (0,3)
        to [short, i = $I$, -*] (3,3) -- (6,3)
        to [R = $R_2$, v = $U_2$, i = $I_2$] (6,0) -- (0,0)
  (3,3) to [R = $R_1$, v = $U_1$, i = $I_1$, -*] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

This is very easy and intuitive. But when I want to add mesh arrow to the circuit, I use (in addition to above code; mesh one as example):

```
\draw
 %
 % mesh one (detailed explanation of the implementation)
 %
 [<-,% direction of the arrow
 > = triangle 45,% kind of the arrow end
 path picture =% allows ''to paint a picture'' inside of an other ''picture''
 {\node[anchor = center]% position of the inner ''picture''
 at (path picture bounding box.center)% bordering rectangle,
                                      % centered inside the arrow (arrow is the outer ''picture'')
 {$M_1$};}]% text of the inner ''picture''
 (1.75,1)% coordinates of the arrow end
 arc% arc-shaped arrow
 (-60:% angle of the arrow start
 170:% angle of the arrow end
 .5);% radius of the arc
```

For the result of both code pieces, see the link above (my initial question).

This amount of code for "just" one arrow seems for me a bit to much, complicated and not intuitive.

What I want:

**1.** Placing parts of circuit (as nodes with names) relative to each other, like the "Petri-Net" example in the `PGF` manual on page 51 (subsection 3.8):

[image: Petri-Net]

Combined with the `circuitikz` syntax (see the first code example).

**2.** Using the names of circuit parts to place mesh arrows intuitive with the `controls` macro (page 748, `PGF` manual), like John Kormylo did in his answer to my initial question:

```
\node (M 3) [below] at (0,0) {\phantom{$M_3$}};% reserving space for M 3 under the circuit
\draw
[->, > = triangle 45] (current bounding box.east) .. controls
                      (current bounding box.south east) ..
                      (M 3.south) node[above, pos = .95] {$M_3$};% see below
% above: location of the inscription ''M_3'' relative to the arrow end
% pos=: location of the inscription ''M_3'' on the ''x''-axis (arrow beginning is zero,
%                                                              arrow end is one)
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this? I hope you understand my intention.

Thank you for your answers and help in advance!

Comment: When node are placed using above, below, left and right it is to make sure there is room for the node contents.  In addition one can use relative coordinates like +(1,1) or ++(1,1).  With the calc library one can interpolate, extrapolate or move at a relative angle to other coordinates.

Comment: You can definitely combine the node positioning from the manual example with the circuitikz syntax. Just define the nodes as in the manual example. You can then use your same circuitikz code, replacing the node coordinates with their names. In this case, since you don't actually want to draw anything there you can use `\coordinate` in place of `\node` (and omit the text label). Unfortunately I don't see any good way to refer to locations of the components drawn by circuitikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of placing the node in the center of the arc, I placed the arc around the node.  Same result, fewer keystrokes.  There are also a number of ways to avoid repeating the same options over and over.  I used a scope since the changes only last for the duration of the scope.

Most of the simplification is due to removing the comments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      %
      % circuit
      %
      \draw
      (0,0) to [V = $U$] (0,3)
            to [short, i = $I$, -*] (3,3) -- (6,3)
            to [R = $R_2$, v = $U_2$, i = $I_2$] (6,0) -- (0,0)
      (3,3) to [R = $R_1$, v = $U_1$, i = $I_1$, -*] (3,0);
      %
      % mesh arrows
      %
      \begin{scope}[>=triangle 45]
        \draw[<-] (1.5,1.5) node{$M_1$} +(.25,-.433) arc(-60:170:.5);
        \draw[<-] (4.5,1.5) node{$M_2$} +(.25,-.433) arc(-60:170:.5);
        \node (mesh3) [below] at (0,0) {\phantom{$M_3$}};% reserve space below circuit for M_3
        \draw[->, thick] (current bounding box.east)% not the only way, just easy
          .. controls (current bounding box.south east) .. 
          (mesh3.south) node[above,pos=.9] {$M_3$};
      \end{scope}
    \end{circuitikz}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    %
    % equations for mesh and knot
    %
    \begin{align*}
      &K  : \quad I   = I_1 + I_2\\
      &M_1: \quad -U  = -U_1\Leftrightarrow U = U_1 = R_1I_1\\
      &M_2: \quad U_1 = -U_2\\
      &M_3: \quad -U  = -U_2\Leftrightarrow U = U_2 = R_2I_2
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello John! Thank you for your answer! Is is a great help for me! Sorry for too much comments.

Comment: Comments are good.  Generally code should have more, not less.

Comment: Hello @John and everybody! How can I understand `+(value, value)` syntax precisely? I red about it in the `TikZ & PGF` manual on page 38 [link] (http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), but I don't get it. Thank you for your answers and help in advance!

Comment: It only matters if you have more than one.   (x,y),  (0,0)+(x,y) and (0,0)++(x,y) all locate the same point.  With (0,0)+(x,y)+(x,y) the second +(x,y) is also relative to (0,0) and winds up again at (x,y), whereas (0,0)++(x,y)++(x,y) winds up at (2x,2y).

Comment: Hello @John and everybody! Excuse me for taking your time. My fault, but I still don't understand it. Could you please explain it in some other way? Meaningful examples are always helpful. Maybe with pictures. And how you calculated the numbers `.25` and `-.433` (in the `+(value, value)` syntax)? Thank you for your answers and help in advance!